# Change product option price dynamically in Magneto 2.4.6

Tags: price, custom-options, magento2.4.6

I want to change product option price dynamically in Product Detail Page.

**For Example:**

In admin i have set **White Color Price $10.00** but i want to change that price based on some condition.

[image]

**I'm looking for event/observer to change that price on fronted.**

[image]

**Note** : I want to change price of **"Customizable Options".**

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: You can use catalog_controller_product_view event, it might resolve your problem.

Comment: i checked but not any idea about option price. Can you please give me some link or example for that ? Thank You.